# Webservice Client behind proxy and service needs NTLM authentication

Tags: java, web-services, proxy

I am working on a client which will request web service(**hosted on internet**) which requires NTLM authentication.
Also the host machine on which my client is installed is behind proxy, first the request should
authenticate proxy server and then request would go the web service and do NTLM authentication.

I am able to do NTLM authentication via the help on [NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865165/jax-ws-sharepoint-401-unauthorized-ntlm)

I have generated the stubs via wsimport by first saving wsdl file to local file because through URL I was not able to connect(because I dont know how to set proxy in command line call to wsimport).
I have not used any frameworks like axis2 or cxf. I am using Java 1.7

When I deploy the client on non-proxy machine(direct internet), then it works but not when behind proxy. Please help.

Comment: Hi @nanosoft I'm developing a new service to do NTLM authentication https://www.nafiux.com/wasp/ if I can help you please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Following simple line of code to use System Proxy did the trick.

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
```